# Print to PDF intermittently fails -- is is this logged?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, event-log, print-to-pdf

Referencing many how-to guides:

https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/fixed-microsoft-print-to-pdf-feature-not-working

on a Windows 10 PC where I'm just a user the print-to-PDF feature will intermittently fail and not work.  The specific fix is unknown, but apparently fixable.

In this case, it's a pop-up window from the browser which I'm trying to print.

In retrospect I realize that I didn't look in the event viewer.  Aside from adding and removing printers not sure how to fix this glitch.  visually, the screen "flashes" but there's no message about printing -- and no documents are printed.

What am I looking for in the event viewer to shed light on this?

Comment: See if there is an error related to this in Reliability History. If so, what app is failing?

Comment: I've always printed to pdf after installing Foxit.  Not sure how to troubleshoot your problem, but print to pdf with Foxit as the default pdf reader has worked great for me, if you're open to a work-around.